# Getting Server error when try to send PUT request with other language

Tags: jmeter

I have some websites where it does not use English, Below is an example text from the website :

> sZápal pľúc netreba podceňovať

If I do **PUT** request to update/modify the content like above, I am getting **Server Error** as a response body and **500** as Error code.

But If I do send exact same JSON **PUT** request with any English sentence in my JSON i.e

> This is JMeter, hello how are you?

I am not getting any error and it works fine.

I am using exact same request header and everything the same in above PUT requests but has error only when I use other languages as part of the JSON PUT request.

Do I need any special settings for multi-language support?

Request headers are given below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given you use [ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) encoding you should be able to send Slovak phrases without any issues
2. Given you use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding you should be able to send whatever you want in any language

So make sure to properly set "Content-Encoding" parameter of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

- With `UTF-8`

  [image]
- With `US-ASCII`

  [image]

You can [enable debug logging in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the [HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dmirti, I was really waiting for the answer and you saved my day :). It works.